# How to add prefix to legend in ng charts using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have created doughnut chart using ng2 charts in angular before the legend I need to add prefix label to legend

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-demo-example

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L1Xa.png)

[image]

need like this

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U64qf.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No default option for it, only way to achieve this is to write a custom plugin which puts the text on the canvas for you.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html